# How to make non-relative JavaFx 'Media'

Tags: java, javafx

Whenever I try to convert a `File` to a JavaFx `Media`, it tries to make the path relative, which I do not want. I'm using a Mac.

This is my code:

```
static String AUDIO_URL_TO_TEST =  "file://Users/Mike/Desktop/calb.mp3";
basicTime.getAudioOutput().setSource(new File(AUDIO_URL_TO_TEST));
```

I've tried almost everything for AUDIO_URL_TO_TEST, such as:

```
static String AUDIO_URL_TO_TEST =  "file:///Users/Mike/Desktop/calb.mp3";
static String AUDIO_URL_TO_TEST =  "file:/c:/Users/Mike/Desktop/calb.mp3";
static String AUDIO_URL_TO_TEST =  "/Users/Mike/Desktop/calb.mp3";
static String AUDIO_URL_TO_TEST =  "~/Users/Mike/Desktop/calb.mp3";
```

This is the code that `setSource()` calls:

```
Media m = new Media(source.getAbsoluteFile().toURI().toURL().toString());
player = new MediaPlayer(m);
```

Media ends up as something like this: `/path/to/eclipse/directory/file://Users/Mike/Desktop/Calb.mp3`, trying to make it relative.

I've tried things other than `source.getAbsoluteFile().toURI().toURL().toString()`, with just as little luck.

A side question: Why does the `Media` class only accept strings? That seems like a horrible design. Strings were meant to contain text, not reference files.

Answer (score 1):

The API doc of Media says:

> The Media class represents a media resource. It is instantiated from
>   the string form of a source URI. ...

So the constructor of it converts the String path to URI. But since none of the example paths in your question is a valid URI, Media treated them as relative paths. For more info please refer to `File`, `URI` and file protocol documentations. The valid URI can be:

```
File f = new File("C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/Calb.mp3");
Media m = new Media(f.toURI().toString());
```

Alternatively,

```
URI uri = new URI("file:///C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/Calb.mp3");
// or
URI uri = new URI("file:/C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/Calb.mp3");
// in short.
Media m = new Media(uri.toString());
```

Comment: For some reason, I was under the impression that `C:` was only for windows machines.

Comment: @MikeG and yes it is.

Comment: So why would the matter on a mac?

Comment: @MikeG, I didn't understand what you mean. So you are on Mac (you should to specify it in your question, I have assumed it as Windows) and you want to a local file with absolute path, right? `new File("/Users/Mike/Desktop/Calb.mp3")` or `new URI("file:///Users/Mike/Desktop/Calb.mp3")` are valid paths then. In addition, since MacOS is case sensitive, in your question you are looking for "calb.mp3" where it is actually "Calb.mp3" or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I managed to get it work by tinkering. I did specify in my question "..., which I do not want. I'm using a Mac" in my first paragraph...